# WinHttpOpen w/ WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NAMED_PROXY returns error 87

Tags: c++, winhttp

I call `WinHttpOpen(nullptr, WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NAMED_PROXY, L"http://127.0.0.1:80/", WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, WINHTTP_FLAG_ASYNC)`, and get a return value of 0 + last error of 87.

Calling `WinHttpOpen(nullptr, WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, WINHTTP_FLAG_ASYNC)` works fine.

Comment: Use WinInet instead

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis - could you, please, elaborate on the motivation to do so?

Comment: More documented and modern API. WinHTTP is obscure. There is no reason to use it unless programming a server.

Comment: 87 is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, so it would seem it wants something different than what you're passing.

Comment: Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082021/code-to-send-an-http-request-through-a-proxy-using-winhttp I would guess the trailing `/` could be the problem.

Comment: The third parameter should be a host name or IP address, not a URL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @Retired Ninja that solved my problem. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as such.